# python tkinter datepicker

Tags: python, tkinter, datepicker

Good evening, complete my request, I'm using the beautiful calendar written by Rambarun Komaljeet, I would like this: when I click on the day I choose, the calendar closes and writes the date in the field "data_operation" this field must be updated later when I read the given by a dq Mysql. I attach the code. Thanks in advance. Paolo (Italy-Bari)

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Author: Rambarun Komaljeet
# License: LGPL
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

import calendar
import tkinter as tk
import time
from tkinter import ttk


class MyDatePicker(tk.Toplevel):
    """
    Description:
        A tkinter GUI date picker.
    """

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """
        Description:
            When instantiating in parent module/widget/Gui, pass in 'self' as argument.
            Ex:
                a = MyDatePicker(self)

        :param parent: parent instance.
        """

        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.title("Date Picker")
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        self.geometry("+250+10")
        self.init_frames()
        self.init_needed_vars()
        self.init_month_year_labels()
        self.init_buttons()
        self.space_between_widgets()
        self.fill_days()
        self.make_calendar()

    def init_frames(self):
        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame1.pack()

        self.frame_days = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame_days.pack()

    def init_needed_vars(self):
        self.month_names = tuple(calendar.month_name)
        self.day_names = tuple(calendar.day_abbr)
        self.year = time.strftime("%Y")
        self.month = time.strftime("%B")

    def init_month_year_labels(self):
        self.year_str_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.month_str_var = tk.StringVar()

        self.year_str_var.set(self.year)
        self.year_lbl = tk.Label(self.frame1, textvariable=self.year_str_var, width=3)
        self.year_lbl.grid(row=0, column=5)

        self.month_str_var.set(self.month)
        self.month_lbl = tk.Label(self.frame1, textvariable=self.month_str_var, width=8)
        self.month_lbl.grid(row=0, column=1)

    def init_buttons(self):
        self.left_yr = ttk.Button(self.frame1, text="←", width=5, command=self.prev_year)
        self.left_yr.grid(row=0, column=4)

        self.right_yr = ttk.Button(self.frame1, text="→", width=5, command=self.next_year)
        self.right_yr.grid(row=0, column=6)

        self.left_mon = ttk.Button(self.frame1, text="←", width=5, command=self.prev_month)
        self.left_mon.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.right_mon = ttk.Button(self.frame1, text="→", width=5, command=self.next_month)
        self.right_mon.grid(row=0, column=2)

    def space_between_widgets(self):
        self.frame1.grid_columnconfigure(3, minsize=40)

    def prev_year(self):
        self.prev_yr = int(self.year_str_var.get()) - 1
        self.year_str_var.set(self.prev_yr)

        self.make_calendar()

    def next_year(self):
        self.next_yr = int(self.year_str_var.get()) + 1
        self.year_str_var.set(self.next_yr)

        self.make_calendar()

    def prev_month(self):
        index_current_month = int(self.month_names.index(self.month_str_var.get()))
        index_prev_month = index_current_month - 1

        #  index 0 is empty string, use index 12 instead, which is index of December.
        if index_prev_month == 0:
            self.month_str_var.set(self.month_names[12])
        else:
            self.month_str_var.set(self.month_names[index_current_month - 1])

        self.make_calendar()

    def next_month(self):
        index_current_month = int(self.month_names.index(self.month_str_var.get()))

        #  index 13 does not exist, use index 1 instead, which is January.
        try:
            self.month_str_var.set(self.month_names[index_current_month + 1])
        except IndexError:
            self.month_str_var.set(self.month_names[1])

        self.make_calendar()

    def fill_days(self):
        col = 0
        #  Creates days label
        for day in self.day_names:
            self.lbl_day = tk.Label(self.frame_days, text=day)
            self.lbl_day.grid(row=0, column=col)
            col += 1

    def make_calendar(self):
        #  Delete date buttons if already present.
        #  Each button must have its own instance attribute for this to work.
        try:
            for dates in self.m_cal:
                for date in dates:
                    if date == 0:
                        continue

                    self.delete_buttons(date)

        except AttributeError:
            pass

        year = int(self.year_str_var.get())
        month = self.month_names.index(self.month_str_var.get())
        self.m_cal = calendar.monthcalendar(year, month)

        #  build date buttons.
        for dates in self.m_cal:
            row = self.m_cal.index(dates) + 1
            for date in dates:
                col = dates.index(date)

                if date == 0:
                    continue

                self.make_button(str(date), str(row), str(col))

    def make_button(self, date, row, column):
        exec(
            "self.btn_" + date + "= ttk.Button(self.frame_days, text=" + date + ", width=5)\n"
            "self.btn_" + date + ".grid(row=" + row + " , column=" + column + ")\n"
            "self.btn_" + date + ".bind(\"<Button-1>\", self.get_date)"
        )

    def delete_buttons(self, date):
        exec(
            "self.btn_" + str(date) + ".destroy()"
        )

    def get_date(self, clicked=None):
        global DATA_OPERAZIONE
        clicked_button = clicked.widget
        year = self.year_str_var.get()
        month = self.month_names.index(self.month_str_var.get())
        date = clicked_button['text']

        #  Change string format for different date formats.
        self.full_date = '%s-%02d-%02d' % (year, month, date)
        print(self.full_date)
        #  insert date in parent widget like these:
        #  in parent: 
        #   self.a = tk.StringVar()
        #   self.parent.a.set(self.full_date)
        #
        #  if a is tk.Entry:
        #   self.parent.a.insert(0, self.full_date)
        #DATA_OPERAZIONE = self.full_date
        #print('data mia',  DATA_OPERAZIONE               )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    def application():
        app = MyDatePicker()
        return DATA_OPERAZIONE


    root = tk.Tk()
    btn = tk.Button(root, text="test", command=application)
    btn.pack()

    # Data Operazione
    DATA_OPERAZIONE = tk.StringVar()
    data_operazione_lbl = tk.Label(root, text="Data Operazione", font=
    `enter code here`('arial', 8), bd=10)
    data_operazione_lbl.pack()

    data_operazione = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=DATA_OPERAZIONE, width=10)
    data_operazione.pack()  


    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I do not see any code.

Comment: Good evening, complete my request, I'm using the beautiful calendar written by Rambarun Komaljeet, I would like this: when I click on the day I choose, the calendar closes and writes the date in the field "data_operation" this field must be updated later when I read the given by a dq Mysql. I attach the code. Thanks in advance. Paolo (Italy-Bari)-----

Answer (score 0):

Please add this to the end of your `get_date` method:

```
data_operazione.delete (0, tk.END)
data_operazione.insert (0, self.full_date)
self.destroy ()
```

Or, try another calendar like the one below:

```
import calendar, datetime
from tkinter import *
class Calendar (Canvas):
    # Create the widget
    def __init__ (self, root, *cnf, **kw):
        """
Construct a calendar widget with all the canvas functionality.
Key words are listed in the config function's help.
        """
        try:
            self.levels = kw ["levels"]
            del kw ["levels"]
        except:
            try:
                self.levels = kw ["Levels"]
                del kw ["Levels"]
            except: self.levels = 3
        try:
            self.close = kw ["close_action"]
            del kw ["close_action"]
        except:
            try:
                self.close = kw ["Close_action"]
                del kw ["Close_action"]
            except:
                try:
                    self.close = kw ["close_Action"]
                    del kw ["close_Action"]
                except:
                    try:
                        self.close = kw ["Close_Action"]
                        del kw ["Close_Action"]
                    except: self.close = 2
        self.sup, self.cur, self.root, self.cal, self.year, self.month, self.level, self.added, self.end = super (Calendar, self), [0, 0, 1, datetime.date.today().year, datetime.date.today().month], root, calendar.TextCalendar (), datetime.date.today().year, datetime.date.today().month, 2 if self.levels > 1 else 3, 0, False
        self.sup.__init__ (root, *cnf, **kw)
        self.rect = self.create_rectangle (0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.bind ("<Configure>", lambda event: self.__setup ())
        self.root.bind ("<Up>", lambda event: self.__upLevel ())
        self.root.bind ("<Down>", lambda event: self.__downLevel ())
        self.root.bind ("<Right>", lambda event: self.__down ())
        self.root.bind ("<Left>", lambda event: self.__up ())
    # Give the user an option to reconfigure the calendar
    def config (self, **kw):
        """
Configure the calendar widget.
Key words that are not standard for a tkinter canvas are listed below:

levels=
    Allowed user accuracy of the calendar.
    1 = Month
    2 = Day
    3 = 10 minutes
    The default is 3.
    (levels/Levels)

close_action=
    What happens when user clicks the 'OK' button.
    1 = Remove from the window
    2 = Disable the calendar
    The default is 2.
    (close_action/Close_action/close_Action/Close_Action)
        """
        try:
            self.levels = kw ["levels"]
            del kw ["levels"]
        except:
            try:
                self.levels = kw ["Levels"]
                del kw ["Levels"]
            except: pass
        try:
            self.close = kw ["close_action"]
            del kw ["close_action"]
        except:
            try:
                self.close = kw ["Close_action"]
                del kw ["Close_action"]
            except:
                try:
                    self.close = kw ["close_Action"]
                    del kw ["close_Action"]
                except:
                    try:
                        self.close = kw ["Close_Action"]
                        del kw ["Close_Action"]
                    except: pass
        if 4 - self.levels > self.level: self.level = 4 - self.levels
        self.sup.config (**kw)
        self.__setup ()
    # Draw the calendar on the canvas
    def __setup (self):
        self.root.update ()
        width, height = self.winfo_width (), self.winfo_height ()
        if height < 80: height = 80
        if width < 120: width = 120
        self.delete (ALL)
        if self.level != 3:
            a = [self.create_polygon ((40, 0), (width - 40, 0), (width - 20, 20), (20, 20), fill = "red", outline = "black"),
                 self.create_line (int (width / 2) - 10, 15, int (width / 2), 5, width = 2),
                 self.create_line (int (width / 2) + 10, 15, int (width / 2), 5, width = 2)]
            for i in a: self.tag_bind (i, "<Button-1>", lambda event: self.__upLevel ())
        if self.level != 4 - self.levels:
            a = [self.create_polygon ((40, height), (width - 40, height), (width - 20, height - 20), (20, height - 20), fill = "red", outline = "black"),
                 self.create_line (int (width / 2) - 10, height - 15, int (width / 2), height - 5, width = 2),
                 self.create_line (int (width / 2) + 10, height - 15, int (width / 2), height - 5, width = 2)]
            for i in a: self.tag_bind (i, "<Button-1>", lambda event: self.__downLevel ())
        a = [self.create_polygon ((0, 40), (20, 20), (20, height - 20), (0, height - 40), fill = "red", outline = "black"),
             self.create_line (15, int (height / 2) - 10, 5, int (height / 2), width = 2),
             self.create_line (15, int (height / 2) + 10, 5, int (height / 2), width = 2)]
        for i in a: self.tag_bind (i, "<Button-1>", lambda event: self.__up ())
        a = [self.create_polygon ((width, 40), (width - 20, 20), (width - 20, height - 20), (width, height - 40), fill = "red", outline = "black"),
             self.create_line (width - 15, int (height / 2) - 10, width - 5, int (height / 2), width = 2),
             self.create_line (width - 15, int (height / 2) + 10, width - 5, int (height / 2), width = 2)]
        for i in a: self.tag_bind (i, "<Button-1>", lambda event: self.__down ())
        a = [self.create_polygon ((35, height - 20), (width - 35, height - 20), (width - 55, height - 40), (55, height - 40), fill = "red", outline = "black"),
             self.create_text (int (width / 2), height - 30, text = "OK")]
        for i in a: self.tag_bind (i, "<Button-1>", lambda event: self.__ok ())
        if self.level == 3:
            if width - 40 < height - 80: self.height, self.width = (width - 40) / 4, (width - 40) / 3
            else: self.width, self.height = (height - 80) / 3, (height - 80) / 4
            self.create_text (int (width / 2), 30, text = str (self.cur [3]))
            font = ("Courier New", int (self.height * 0.45 - 1))
            if font [1] < 1: font  = ("Courier New", 1)
            for y in range (4):
                for x in range (3):
                    b = [self.create_rectangle (x * self.width + 20, y * self.height + 40, x * self.width + self.width + 20, y * self.height + self.height + 40, fill = "white"),
                         self.create_text (x * self.width + (self.width / 2) + 20, y * self.height + (self.height / 2) + 40, text = calendar.month_abbr [y * 3 + x + 1], font = font)]
                    for i in b: self.tag_bind (i, "<Button-1>", lambda event, x = x, y = y: self.__click (y, x, None))
                    if y * 3 + x + 1 == self.cur [4]: self.__click (y, x, None)
        elif self.level == 2:
            self.rows = len (self.cal.monthdayscalendar (*self.cur [3 : ]))
            if width - 40 < height - 80: self.height, self.width = (width - 40) / self.rows, (width - 40) / 7
            else: self.width, self.height = (height - 80) / 7, (height - 80) / self.rows
            font = ("Courier New", int (self.height * 0.45))
            self.create_text (int (width / 2), 30, text = calendar.month_name [self.cur [4]] + " " + str (self.cur [3]))
            if font [1] < 1: font = ("Courier New", 1)
            for w, week in enumerate (self.cal.monthdayscalendar (*self.cur [3 : ])):
                for d, day in enumerate (week):
                    if day:
                        b = [self.create_rectangle (d * self.width + 20, w * self.height + 40, d * self.width + self.width + 20, w * self.height + self.height + 40, fill = "white"),
                             self.create_text (d * self.width + (self.width / 2) + 20, w * self.height + (self.height / 2) + 40, text = day, font = font)]
                        for i in b: self.tag_bind (i, "<Button-1>", lambda event, w = w, d = d, day = day: self.__click (w, d, day))
                    if day == self.cur [2]: self.__click (w, d, day)
        else:
            if width - 40 < height - 80: self.height, self.width = (width - 40) / 24, (width - 40) / 6
            else: self.width, self.height = (height - 80) / 6, (height - 80) / 24
            font = ("Courier New", int (self.height * 0.45 - 1))
            self.create_text (int (width / 2), 30, text = "%s %s %s" % (self.__dayToPosition (self.cur [2]), calendar.month_name [self.cur [4]], str (self.cur [3])))
            if font [1] < 1: font  = ("Courier New", 1)
            for h in range (24):
                for m in range (0, 6):
                    b = [self.create_rectangle (m * self.width + 20, h * self.height + 40, m * self.width + self.width + 20, h * self.height + self.height + 40, fill = "white"),
                         self.create_text (m * self.width + (self.width / 2) + 20, h * self.height + (self.height / 2) + 40, text = "%s:%s" % (h if h >= 10 else "0" + str (h), m * 10 if m > 0 else "00"), font = font)]
                    for i in b: self.tag_bind (i, "<Button-1>", lambda event, h = h, m = m: self.__click (h, m, None))
                    if h == self.cur [1] and m * 10 == self.cur [0]: self.__click (h, m , None)
        if self.end:
            self.tag_bind (ALL, "<Button-1>", lambda event: None)
            self.create_rectangle (0, 0, width, height, fill = "black", stipple = "gray50")
    # Format and return the selected date (and time)
    def get (self):
        """
Get the day selected by the user
        """
        cur = self.cur
        a = cur [4]
        cur [4] = cur [3]
        cur [3] = a
        cur.insert (3, calendar.month_abbr [a])
        cur.insert (2, calendar.day_abbr [datetime.datetime (cur [5], cur [4], cur [2]).weekday ()])
        cur [0] = "%s:%s" % (cur [1] if cur [1] >= 10 else "0" + str (cur [1]), cur [0] if cur [0] >= 10 else "0" + str (cur [0]))
        del cur [1]
        return cur [6 - self.levels * 2 : ]
    # Handle the mouse clicks
    def __click (self, w, d, day):
        self.delete (self.rect)
        self.rect = self.create_rectangle (d * self.width + 21, w * self.height + 41, d * self.width + self.width + 20, w * self.height + self.height + 40, fill = "red", stipple = "gray25", width = 0),
        if self.level == 3: self.cur = [self.cur [0], self.cur [1], self.cur [2], self.cur [3], w * 3 + d + 1]
        elif self.level == 2: self.cur = [self.cur [0], self.cur [1], day, self.cur [3], self.cur [4]]
        else: self.cur = [d * 10, w, self.cur [2], self.cur [3], self.cur [4]]
    # Move the calendar
    def __up (self):
        if self.level == 3: self.cur [3] -= 1
        elif self.level == 2:
            self.cur [4] -= 1
            if self.cur [4] < 1: self.cur = [self.cur [0], self.cur [1], self.cur [2], self.cur [3] - 1, 12]
        else:
            self.cur [2] -= 1
            if self.cur [2] < 1: self.cur = [self.cur [0], self.cur [1], calendar.monthrange (self.cur [3], self.cur [4] - 1 if self.cur [4] - 1 > 0 else 12) [1], self.cur [3], self.cur [4] - 1]
            if self.cur [4] < 1: self.cur = [self.cur [0], self.cur [1], self.cur [2], self.cur [3] - 1, 12]
        self.__setup ()
    def __down (self):
        if self.level == 3: self.cur [3] += 1
        elif self.level == 2:
            self.cur [4] += 1
            if self.cur [4] > 12: self.cur = [self.cur [0], self.cur [1], self.cur [2], self.cur [3] + 1, 1]
        else:
            self.cur [2] += 1
            if self.cur [2] > calendar.monthrange (self.cur [3], self.cur [4]) [1]: self.cur = [self.cur [0], self.cur [1], 1, self.cur [3], self.cur [4] + 1]
            if self.cur [4] > 12: self.cur = [self.cur [0], self.cur [1], self.cur [2], self.cur [3] + 1, 1]
        self.__setup ()
    # Move calendar level
    def __upLevel (self):
        if self.level < 3:
            self.level += 1
            self.__setup ()
    def __downLevel (self, release = False):
        if self.level > 4 - self.levels:
            self.level -= 1
            self.__setup ()
    # Format a number to named position (e.g. 1 -> 1st)
    def __dayToPosition (self, num):
        if num > 9 and str(num) [-2] == '1': return str (num) + 'th'
        lastDigit = num % 10
        if (lastDigit == 1): return str (num) + 'st'
        elif (lastDigit == 2): return str (num) + 'nd'
        elif (lastDigit == 3): return str (num) + 'rd'
        else: return str (num) + 'th'
    # Handle when the user clicks ok
    def __ok (self):
        if self.close == 1:
            if self.added == 1: self.pack_remove ()
            elif self.added == 2: self.grid_remove ()
            elif self.added == 3: self.place_remove ()
        elif self.added == 2:
            self.end = True
            self.__setup ()
    # The demonstration method
    def demo ():
        """
This method is a demostration of the widget. It creates it's own 'Tk' app to put it on.
        """
        root = Tk ()
        root.title ("Calendar Demo")
        c = Calendar (root)
        c.grid (sticky = "nsew")
        #help (Calendar)
        root.mainloop ()
        print (c.get ())
    # Configure the geometry managers
    def pack (self, *cnf, **kw):
        self.added = 1
        self.sup.pack (*cnf, **kw)
        self.__setup ()
    def pack_configure (self, *cnf, **kw):
        self.sup.pack_configure (*cnf, **kw)
        self.__setup ()
    def grid (self, *cnf, **kw):
        self.sup.grid (*cnf, **kw)
        coords, self.added = [(child.grid_info () ["column"], child.grid_info () ["row"]) for child in self.root.children.values () if child == self] [0], 2
        try: [Grid.columnconfigure (self.root, coords [0] + x, weight = 1) for x in range (kw ["columnspan"])]
        except KeyError: Grid.columnconfigure (self.root, coords [0], weight = 1)
        try: [Grid.rowconfigure (self.root, coords [1] + y, weight = 1) for y in range (kw ["rowspan"])]
        except KeyError: Grid.rowconfigure (self.root, coords [1], weight = 1)
        self.__setup ()
    def grid_configure (self, *cnf, **kw):
        self.sup.grid_configure (*cnf, **kw)
        self.__setup ()
    def place (self, *cnf, **kw):
        self.added = 3
        self.sup.place (*cnf, **kw)
        self.__setup ()
    def place_configure (self, *cnf, **kw):
        self.sup.place_configure (*cnf, **kw)
        self.__setup ()
if __name__ == "__main__": Calendar.demo ()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #Abhinandan
import sys
import datetime
import calendar
from functools import partial
from ui.entrymaxlength import DateIntegerEntry
import os
import platform

try:
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import Widget

except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import Widget

try:
    from tkinter import font as tkf
except ImportError:
    import tkFont as tkf

try:
    from tkinter import ttk
except ImportError:
    import ttk

try:
    import babel
    import babel.dates
    import babel.numbers
except ImportError:
    babel = None


DEFAULT_FONT = ('TkTextFont',)
DEFAULT_FONT='Times 12'
#DEFAULT_FONT=("Calibri",14)
class TargetShape():
    """How to draw the target round a date"""

    Square = 'square'
    Rectangle = 'rectangle'
    Circle = 'circle'


class DateEntry(tk.Frame, object):
    """A date entry widget

    Creates a frame which contains entry boxes for Year, Month and Day and a
    button to display a date selection dialog.

    Dates will always consist of a 4 digit year and 2 digit months and days
    only the order and separator are determined by the `locale` parameter

    :param master: The master frame
    :type master: :class:`ttk.Frame`
    :param start_date: The date to display in the entry boxes
    :type start_date:  :class:`datetime.date` or :class:`datetime.datetime`
    :param locale: Determines the order of the widgets in the entry.
                   Either a locale name e.g. 'en' or a babel Locale
                   instance. If :mod:`babel` is not installed ISO 8601
                   format will be used.
    :type locale:  str
    :param font: Tk font to use. Default TkTextFont
    :type font: tuple
    """
    start_date=None
    def __init__(self, master,
                 start_date=None,state=None,separator='-',
                 locale='en',bg='white',
                 font=DEFAULT_FONT, frame_look={}, **look):
        args = dict(relief=tk.SUNKEN, border=1)
        args.update(frame_look)        

        super(DateEntry, self,).__init__(master,bg=bg, **args )#style='tks.TFrame')

        args = {'relief': tk.FLAT,'border':0}
        args.update(look)

        if babel and locale:
            if not isinstance(locale, babel.Locale):
                locale = babel.Locale(locale)

            pattern = locale.date_formats['short'].pattern

            for ch in pattern:
                if ch.lower() not in ['d', 'm', 'y']:
                    separator = ch
                    break

            elems = pattern.split(separator)
            for idx, elem in enumerate(elems):
                if 'y' in elem:
                    year_column = idx
                elif 'M' in elem:
                    month_column = idx
                elif 'd' in elem:
                    day_column = idx
        else:
            day_column = 0
            month_column = 1
            year_column = 2
            separator = separator

        self._locale = locale
        self._font = tkf.Font(font=font)
        self.day_entry=None
        self.month_entry=None


        self.year_entry=None
        self._year_var = tk.IntVar()
        self._month_var = tk.IntVar()
        self._day_var = tk.IntVar()

        self._time = None

        self.day_entry = DateIntegerEntry(self,maxvalue=31,
                                       maxlength=2,textvariable=self._day_var,bg=bg,justify=tk.RIGHT,
                                       width=2,
                                       font=self._font,state=state,**args)
        self.day_entry.grid(row=0, column=day_column * 2)
        self.day_entry.bind('<KeyRelease>',self.checkFocusNext)

        #self._day_var.set('%d' % self.date.day)
        self.month_entry = DateIntegerEntry(self,maxlength=2,maxvalue=12,
                                         textvariable=self._month_var,bg=bg,justify=tk.RIGHT,
                                         width=2,
                                         font=self._font,state=state,**args)        
        self.month_entry.grid(row=0, column=month_column * 2)
        self.month_entry.bind('<KeyRelease>',self.checkFocusNext)

        '''self.day_entry = ttk.Combobox(self,
                                       textvariable=self._day_var,
                                       width=3,
                                       font=self._font,state=state)
        self._update_day_values(self.date.year,
                                self.date.month,
                                self.date.day)
        self.day_entry.grid(row=0, column=day_column * 2)
        self.month_entry = ttk.Combobox(self,
                                         textvariable=self._month_var,
                                         width=3,
                                         font=self._font,state=state)
        self.month_entry['values'] = ['%d' % (x + 1) for x in range(12)]
        self._month_var.set('%d' % self.date.month)
        self.month_entry.grid(row=0, column=month_column * 2)
        self.month_entry.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self._month_updated)
        '''

        self.month_entry.bind('<FocusOut>', self._month_updated)
        #self._year_var.set(self.date.year)
        self.year_entry = DateIntegerEntry(self,maxlength=4,maxvalue=9999,
                                     textvariable=self._year_var,justify=tk.RIGHT,
                                     width=4,
                                     font=self._font,bg=bg,state=state,**args)
        #self._year_var.set(1111)

        self.year_entry.grid(row=0, column=year_column * 2)

        self.year_entry.bind('<KeyRelease>',self.checkFocusNext)
        self.year_entry.bind('<FocusOut>',self._month_updated)
        self.lbl1 = tk.Label(self, text=separator,bg='white',**args)
        self.lbl1.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.lbl2 = tk.Label(self, text=separator,bg='white' ,**args)
        self.lbl2.grid(row=0, column=3)
        self.day_entry.bind('<Return>', self.focusNext)
        self.month_entry.bind('<Return>', self.focusNext)
        self.year_entry.bind('<Return>', self.focusNext)   
        self.day_entry.bind('<Right>',self.next1)     
        self.month_entry.bind('<Right>', self.next1)
        self.year_entry.bind('<Right>', self.next1) 
        self.day_entry.bind('<Left>',self.prev)     
        self.month_entry.bind('<Left>', self.prev)
        self.year_entry.bind('<Left>', self.prev)
        self.day_entry.bind('<Up>',self.checkUp)     
        self.day_entry.bind('<Down>',self.checkDown) 
        self.month_entry.bind('<Up>',self.checkUp)     
        self.month_entry.bind('<Down>',self.checkDown)            

        self.year_entry.bind('<Up>',self.checkUp)     
        self.year_entry.bind('<Down>',self.checkDown)            
        self.day_entry.bind('<FocusIn>',self.setFocus)     
        self.month_entry.bind('<FocusIn>',self.setFocus)            

        self.year_entry.bind('<FocusIn>',self.setFocus) 




        if platform.system()=='Linux':
            self.day_entry.bind('<Shift-ISO_Left_Tab>',self.focusPrev)     
            self.month_entry.bind('<Shift-ISO_Left_Tab>',self.focusPrev)            

            self.year_entry.bind('<Shift-ISO_Left_Tab>',self.focusPrev) 

        else:
            self.day_entry.bind('<Shift-Tab>',self.focusPrev)     
            self.month_entry.bind('<Shift-Tab>',self.focusPrev)            

            self.year_entry.bind('<Shift-Tab>',self.focusPrev) 

        self.day_entry.bind('<Tab>',self.focusNext)     
        self.month_entry.bind('<Tab>',self.focusNext)            

        self.year_entry.bind('<Tab>',self.focusNext) 
        self.start_date=start_date
        if start_date is None:
            self.date = datetime.date.today()
        else:
            self.date = start_date        #btn = ttk.Button(self, text=_('Select...'), command=self._select_date)
        #btn.grid(row=0, column=5, sticky=tk.E, padx=(6, 0))

        for idx in range(5):
            self.columnconfigure(idx, weight=0)
        #self.day_entry.focus()
        #self.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.day_entry.bind('<FocusOut>',self.checkDate)     
        self.month_entry.bind('<FocusOut>',self.checkDate)            

        self.year_entry.bind('<FocusOut>',self.checkDate) 




    def focusNext(self,event=None):
        #print('next')

        #event.widget.tk_focusPrev().focus()
        if event.widget.tk_focusNext().winfo_parent()==event.widget.winfo_parent() :
            if event.widget.tk_focusNext().winfo_parent()==event.widget.tk_focusNext().tk_focusNext().winfo_parent():
                #event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()
                event.widget.tk_focusNext().tk_focusNext().tk_focusNext().focus()
                return("break")
            else:
                event.widget.tk_focusNext().tk_focusNext().focus()
                return("break")

        else:

            event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()
            return("break")

    def focusPrev(self,event=None):
        #print('prev')
        if event.widget.tk_focusPrev().winfo_parent()==event.widget.winfo_parent() :
            if event.widget.tk_focusPrev().winfo_parent()==event.widget.tk_focusPrev().tk_focusPrev().winfo_parent():
                event.widget.tk_focusPrev().tk_focusPrev().tk_focusPrev().focus()
                return("break")
            else:
                event.widget.tk_focusPrev().tk_focusPrev().focus()
                return("break")
        else:
            event.widget.tk_focusPrev().focus()

    def setFocus(self,event=None):
        event.widget.selection_range(0,tk.END)

    def checkUp(self,event):
        value=event.widget.get()
        if len(value)>0:

            value=int(value)+1
            event.widget.delete(0,tk.END)
            if len(str(value))==1:
                value='0'+str(value)
            event.widget.insert(0,value)
            if len(event.widget.get())==0:
                event.widget.insert(0,'01') 
            event.widget.selection_range(0,tk.END)
        else:
            event.widget.insert(0,'01') 
        return("break")    
    def checkDown(self,event):
        value=event.widget.get()
        if len(value)>0:

            value=int(value)-1
            event.widget.delete(0,tk.END)
            if value!=0:
                if len(str(value))==1:
                    value='0'+str(value)
                event.widget.insert(0,value)
            else:
                event.widget.insert(0,"01")

            if len(event.widget.get())==0:

                event.widget.insert(0,event.widget.getMaxvalue())
            event.widget.selection_range(0,tk.END)
        else:
            event.widget.insert(0,'01')                 
        return("break")    
    def prev(self,event):

        if  event.widget.selection_present()==True:
            if event.widget.tk_focusPrev().winfo_parent()==event.widget.winfo_parent() :
                event.widget.tk_focusPrev().focus()
                event.widget.tk_focusPrev().selection_range(0,tk.END)



        elif event.widget.index(tk.INSERT)==0:
            if event.widget.tk_focusPrev().winfo_parent()==event.widget.winfo_parent() :
                if len(event.widget.get())>0:

                    event.widget.tk_focusPrev().focus()
                    event.widget.tk_focusPrev().selection_range(0,tk.END)
                event.widget.selection_range(0,tk.END)

            return("break")    
    def next(self,event):

        event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()
        event.widget.tk_focusNext().selection_range(0,tk.END)
        return("break")        

    def next1(self,event):
        #print(event.widget.index(tk.END),len(str(event.widget.getMaxvalue())))

        if  event.widget.selection_present()==True:

            if event.widget.tk_focusNext().winfo_parent()==event.widget.winfo_parent():
                event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()
                event.widget.tk_focusNext().selection_range(0,tk.END)
            else:
                event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()
            return("break") 

        elif event.widget.index(tk.INSERT)==event.widget.index(tk.END):


            if event.widget.tk_focusNext().winfo_parent()==event.widget.winfo_parent():
                if len(event.widget.get())>0:
                    event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()
                    event.widget.tk_focusNext().selection_range(0,tk.END)
                    #return("break")         


            else:
                if len(event.widget.get())==4:
                    event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()
            event.widget.selection_range(0,tk.END)

            return("break") 

        #return("break")         


    def stateDisable(self):
        self.config(bg='lightgrey')
        self.lbl1.config(bg='lightgrey')
        self.lbl2.config(bg='lightgrey')
        self.day_entry.config(disabledbackground='lightgrey')
        self.month_entry.config(disabledbackground='lightgrey')
        self.year_entry.config(disabledbackground='lightgrey')
        self.day_entry.config(state='disable')
        self.month_entry.config(state='disable')
        self.year_entry.config(state='disable')



    #def Bindnext(self):



    def stateNormal(self):
        self.config(bg='white')

        self.lbl1.config(bg='white')
        self.lbl2.config(bg='white')
        self.day_entry.config(state='normal')
        self.month_entry.config(state='normal')
        self.year_entry.config(state='normal')

    def stateReadOnly(self):
        self.config(bg='lightgrey')
        self.lbl1.config(bg='lightgrey')
        self.lbl2.config(bg='lightgrey')
        self.day_entry.config(disabledbackground='lightgrey')
        self.month_entry.config(disabledbackground='lightgrey')
        self.year_entry.config(disabledbackground='lightgrey')
        self.day_entry.config(state='readonly')
        self.month_entry.config(state='readonly')
        self.year_entry.config(state='readonly')    

    def focus(self):
        self.day_entry.focus()


    def setDate(self,d):
        #self._year_var.set(d.year)
        #self._month_var.set('%d'% d.month)
        #self._day_var.set('%d' %d.day)
        print(d.year)
        print(d.month)
        print(d.day)

        day=d.day
        month=d.month
        if len(str(d.day))==1:
            day='0'+str(d.day)
        if len(str(d.month))==1:
            month='0'+str(d.month) 

        self.day_entry.setMaxvalue(31)

        self.day_entry.delete(0,tk.END)
        self.month_entry.delete(0,tk.END)
        self.year_entry.delete(0,tk.END)
        self.year_entry.insert(0,d.year)
        #self._month_updated()
        self.month_entry.insert(0,month)
        self._month_updated()

        self.day_entry.insert(0, day)

        if isinstance(d, datetime.datetime):
            self._time = d.time()
        else:
            self._time = None 

    def getDate(self):

        try:
            d = datetime.datetime(year=int(self.year_entry.get()),
                                  month=int(self.month_entry.get()),
                                  day=int(self.day_entry.get()))

            if self._time:
                d = d.replace(hour=self._time.hour,
                              minute=self._time.minute,
                              second=self._time.second)

            return d
        except:
            if self.start_date==None:
                self.setDate(datetime.date.today())
                self.focus()
                return self.getDate()
            else:
                self.setDate( self.start_date)
                self.focus()
                return self.getDate()







    def dateEvent(self,event,function):
        d = datetime.datetime(year=self._year_var.get(),
                              month=self._month_var.get(),
                              day=self._day_var.get())

        if self._time:
            d = d.replace(hour=self._time.hour,
                          minute=self._time.minute,
                          second=self._time.second)
        self.year_entry.bind(event,function)
        self.day_entry.bind(event,function)
        self.month_entry.bind(event,function)




    def _month_updated(self, event=None):
        """Update the day entry so that we have the correct end date for
        the month
        """
        if len(self.year_entry.get())>0 and len(self.month_entry.get())>0 and len(self.day_entry.get())>0:
            self._update_day_values(int(self.year_entry.get()),
                                    int(self.month_entry.get()),
                                    int(self.day_entry.get()))    

    def _update_day_values(self, year, month, day):
        """Update the day entry  with the correct values
        """
        _, days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(year, month)

        new_day = None
        if day:
            current_last_day =self.day_entry.getMaxvalue()#int(self.day_entry['values'][-1])
            if current_last_day > days_in_month and day > days_in_month:
                new_day = days_in_month

        #self.day_entry.setMaxvalue(days_in_month)

        if new_day:
            self.day_entry.delete(0,tk.END)
            self.day_entry.insert(0,new_day)
            #self._day_var.set('%d' % new_day)    

    '''def _update_day_values(self, year, month, day):
        """Update the day combo box with the correct values
        """
        _, days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(year, month)

        new_day = None
        if self.day_entry['values']:
            current_last_day = int(self.day_entry['values'][-1])
            if current_last_day > days_in_month and day > days_in_month:
                new_day = days_in_month

        self.day_entry['values'] = \
            ['%d' % (x + 1) for x in range(days_in_month)]

        if new_day:
            self._day_var.set('%d' % new_day)
    def _month_updated(self, event=None):
        """Update the day combo box so that we have the correct end date for
        the month
        """
        self._update_day_values(self._year_var.get(),
                                self._month_var.get(),
                                self._day_var.get())'''

    @property
    def date(self):
        """The :class:`~datetime.date` represented by the entry."""
        if self.day_entry is not None:

            ''''d = datetime.datetime(year=self._year_var.get(),
                                  month=self._month_var.get(),
                                  day=self._day_var.get())

            if self._time:
                d = d.replace(hour=self._time.hour,
                              minute=self._time.minute,
                              second=self._time.second)
            print(self.day_entry.get(),'my value')'''
            d=self.getDate()

            return d




    @date.setter
    def date(self, d):
        self.day_entry.setMaxvalue(31)
        self._year_var.set(d.year)
        self._month_var.set('%d'% d.month)
        self._day_var.set('%d' %d.day)
        print(d.year)
        print(d.month)
        print(d.day)
        day=d.day
        month=d.month
        if len(str(d.day))==1:
            day='0'+str(d.day)
        if len(str(d.month))==1:
            month='0'+str(d.month) 

        if self.day_entry is not None:
            self.day_entry.delete(0,tk.END)
            self.month_entry.delete(0,tk.END)
            self.year_entry.delete(0,tk.END)
            self.year_entry.insert(0,d.year)
            #self._month_updated()
            self.month_entry.insert(0,month)

            self.day_entry.insert(0,day)
            self._month_updated()

        if isinstance(d, datetime.datetime):
            self._time = d.time()
        else:
            self._time = None


    def checkDate(self,event):
        try:
            if len(event.widget.get())==1 and event.widget.getMaxvalue()<50:
                value='0'+str(event.widget.get())

                event.widget.delete(0,tk.END)
                event.widget.insert(0,value)

            if event.widget.focus_get() is None or event.widget is None:
                pass
            else:
                if event.widget.focus_get().winfo_parent()!=event.widget.winfo_parent(): 
                    import datetime
                    correctDate = None


                    try:
                        y=int(self.year_entry.get())
                        m=int(self.month_entry.get())
                        d=int(self.day_entry.get())
                        newDate = datetime.datetime(y,m,d)
                        correctDate = False
                        if newDate>=datetime.datetime(1950,1,1) and newDate<=datetime.datetime(2050,12,31):
                            correctDate=True
                    except:
                        correctDate = False
                    print(str(correctDate))

                    if correctDate==True:
                        pass
                    else:
                        if self.start_date==None:
                            self.setDate(datetime.date.today())
                            self.focus()
                        else:
                            self.setDate( self.start_date)
                            self.focus()

                    #return correctDate
                else:
                    pass
        except:
            pass


    def checkFocusNext(self,event):

        if event.widget.index(tk.INSERT)==event.widget.index(tk.END) and event.widget.selection_present()==False:

            if event.widget.tk_focusNext().winfo_parent()==event.widget.winfo_parent():
                if len(event.widget.get())>0:
                    if event.widget.getMaxvalue()==12 and  int(event.widget.get())>1 or len(event.widget.get())==2:
                        event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()   

                    elif event.widget.getMaxvalue()>12 and int(event.widget.get())>3 or len(event.widget.get())==2 :    
                        event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()
            else:
                if len(event.widget.get())>0:
                    if event.widget.getMaxvalue()>31 and int(event.widget.get())>1950 or len(event.widget.get())==4 :    
                        event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()


            return("break") 



        '''if len(event.widget.get())==2 and event.widget.selection_present()==False:
            event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()
            return False
            #self.next(event)'''

    def setStartDate(self,date):
        self.start_date=date


    def _select_date(self):
        """Display the date selection dialog"""

        d = datetime.date(year=self._year_var.get(),
                          month=self._month_var.get(),
                          day=self._day_var.get())

        dlg = DateDialog(self,
                         _('Select a Date...'),
                         start_date=d,
                         locale=self._locale,
                         font=self._font)
        self.wait_window(dlg)
        new_date = dlg.date
        if new_date != None:
            self.date = new_date

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Date Test')
    '''entry = tk.Entry(root)
    #entry.config(state='readonly')
    #entry.stateDisable()
    entry.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)
    entry = tk.Entry(root)
    #entry.config(state='readonly')
    #entry.stateDisable()
    entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.EW)'''

    d=datetime.datetime.now()
    cwd=d.strptime(str('2018/4/1'),"%Y/%m/%d")
    entry = DateEntry(root,start_date=cwd, locale='pt')
    #entry.config(state='readonly')
    #entry.stateDisable()
    entry.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)
    #entry.setDate(datetime.date.today())


    '''entry = tk.Entry(root)
    #entry.config(state='readonly')
    #entry.stateDisable()
    entry.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=tk.EW)
    entry = tk.Entry(root)
    #entry.config(state='readonly')
    #entry.stateDisable()
    entry.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky=tk.EW)'''





    def show_date():
        #pass
        print(entry.getDate())
        #print(entry.getDate().strftime("%d/%m/%y"))
    tk.Button(root,command=show_date).grid(row=1,column=0)
    #entry.date='2018-1-1'
    #entry.dateEvent('<FocusOut>',abc)

    d=datetime.datetime.now()
    cwd=d.strptime(str('2018/1/1'),"%Y/%m/%d")
    print(cwd)
    entry.date=cwd
    entry.focus()
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    show_date()
    root.mainloop()
```